# How to convert set of fields (text, dropdown etc.) that hides/shows on button click, to a pop up?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, onclick, popup

Currently, i have a few number of fields that shows up and hides on a button click.
I want to transfer some of those fields to a pop-Up (preferably using angular material) . Can you help me with some links?
Also this is in Angular !

Answer (score 0):

Set id on parent tag and on button click hide show functionality.

Otherwise use [Toggle]: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_toggle.asp functunality.